# Selecting Firebase platform for react native application

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native

I'm starting out on a project that will user react native and firebase as the db layer, and I'm wondering what benefits there would be to using [Firebase for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) and [Firebase for IOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup) rather than just using [Firebase for the web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup).

My inclination is to use the web implementation to simplify and standardize the data model API, but I'm wondering if there are great performance gains when using Firebase for Android / IOS. Any insights into this question would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I'm not looking for *recommendations* on which platform to use. I'm trying to understand the specific features and performance stats made available by Firebase for Android/IOS vs Firebase for web. I've been using Firebase for web for several years now but haven't used Firebase for Android/IOS--are there specific features or performance related reasons to use the latter?

Comment: Can you use the FCM with Firebase for the Web on React-Native?

Comment: I think that the answer will depend on what services from the Firebase you are planning to use

Comment: The question is kinda broad and not really answerable without understanding the entire use case? Does your use case call for an app that users can install on their device? If so, then building an iOS app is an option. If not, use web services? Do you know swift? Do you want to spending time learning it if not? What's the end-user experience supposed to be? There are just too many questions that makes this question not well suited for SO. Firebase has a google group that is a bit more free-form as well as a [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/).

Comment: @Jay As I say above, I'm building a React Native app (which means an app that will compile to ObjectiveC for ios and Java for android). Firebase will only provide a database layer for me. Are there reasons to go with anything other than the Firebase for the web in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Currently using firebase for the web with my React Native project and the major advantage for me is that I am more familiar with Javascript than native development, so it was super fast to set it up and add new functionality. So it depends on your comfort level with the three platforms.

Also I change in one place and it affects both versions of the app so thats great.

And finally, I find it easier to find firebase + web help online!